# How to compare effective masses in band structures?

Tags: solid-state-physics, mass, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

As far as I know the effective mass in Solid State Physics is determined by inverse of the slope of dispersion relations (in band structure diagrams).

\begin{equation}
m^*=\frac{\hbar}{\frac{d^2\epsilon}{dk^2}}
\end{equation}

Given a number of band structures I am not sure how to interpret these slopes due to the number of lines in band diagrams. For example take these two band diagrams:

[image: Band diagrams of two different metals]

As far as I can tell I cannot say anything meaningfull about the difference in slopes here and thus neither about the different effective masses. My question therefore: **how can I tell the difference in effective mass between these two diagrams?**